# IgniteException: Query execution failed ScanQuery

Tags: java, gridgain, ignite

I encounter this exception using Ignite

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Query execution failed: GridCacheQueryBean [qry=GridCacheQueryAdapter [type=SCAN, clsName=null, clause=null, filter=org.apache.ignite.yardstick.cache.IgniteScanQueryBenchmark$1@5cbed480, part=null, incMeta=false, metrics=GridCacheQueryMetricsAdapter [minTime=41, maxTime=41, avgTime=41.0, execs=1, fails=1, executed=true], pageSize=1024, timeout=0, keepAll=true, incBackups=false, dedup=false, prj=null, keepPortable=false, subjId=0ae47ff7-9cc1-4b57-88cf-8453f5f21625, taskHash=0], rdc=null, trans=null]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.next(GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.java:166)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy$2.onHasNext(IgniteCacheProxy.java:406)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.hasNextX(GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.java:53)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.GridIteratorAdapter.hasNext(GridIteratorAdapter.java:45)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.QueryCursorImpl.getAll(QueryCursorImpl.java:71)
```

And my code

```
 IgniteBiPredicate<Integer, Person> filter = new IgniteBiPredicate<Integer, Person>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Integer key, Person p) {
            return p.getSalary() >= minSalary && p.getSalary() <= maxSalary;
        }
    };

    QueryCursor<Person> cursor = cache.query(new ScanQuery(filter));

    return cursor.getAll();
```

whats wrong with my code

version

> > > ver. 1.2.0-incubating#20150616-sha1:9fb960ff
> > >       2015 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks correct. But did you provide the whole trace? It should have the cause which gives much more information about the reasons of the failure. You can also check remote nodes logs.

Most likely you had some kind of serialization error. Try the following:

- Convert your predicate to a top level class. Anonymous class has reference to the parent object, so it's possible that you're serializing something that should not be serialized.
- Make sure that the predicate class is available on all nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I understood [Valentin Kulichenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209370/igniteexception-query-execution-failed-scanquery/32217638#32217638) in this thread solves my problem but i had few questions after reading that answer. I like to share my experience in this thread by answering how i had dealt with them

> 1) How do I convert my predicate to a top level class when I am depending on variables and parameters present in enclosing method?

You can introduce those parameters as class variables and do constructor initialization 

This is how i did it

```
   package com.ignite.filters
   public class MatchingClientIdsCondition implements IgniteBiPredicate<String, Object> {

        private String clientId;

        public MatchingClientIdsCondition() {
          super();
        }
        public MatchingClientIdsCondition(String clientId) {
          this.clientId = clientId;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean apply(String key, Object value) {
          return key.matches(clientId + "(.*)");
        }
    }
```

> 2) How should I deploy my predicate class in all nodes?

Move to the base directory of package in which predicate class is present (in my case, i have to move to com directory) and prepare jar File

use the command `jar cvf <jar name> .` to prepare a jar file or You can use export option in eclipse.

copy this JAR to libs folder in all ignite nodes